# JavaFX cannot close scene by Esc using getAccelerators()

Tags: javafx

I can close my stage using 'X', this works:

```
primaryScene.getAccelerators().put(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.X), primaryStage::hide);
```

but cannot close it using Esc, this doesn't work:

```
primaryScene.getAccelerators().put(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ESCAPE), primaryStage::hide);
```

Why and how to fix?